# How to use Oracle TRUNC and NVL function together in JPA Predicate?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I have a specific Oracle query that has the following condition in where clause:

```
SELECT col_a 
FROM table_x
WHERE TRUNC(NVL(date_col, sysdate + 365)) >
     TRUNC(TO_DATE('11-Jan-2001', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));
```

I am unable to figure out how to use CriteriaBuilder to create the where clause Predicate. So far, I have figured out a half way but getting stuck at sysdate + 365 part. I specifically need to get DB date as my application current date and DB current date might differ.

```
Predicate p = criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(
    criteriaBuilder.function("TRUNC", LocalDate.class, root.get(date_col)),
    criteriaBuilder.function("NVL", LocalDate.class, root.get(date_col))
);
```

I'm unable to figure out how to get sysdate + 365 and pass it to criteriaBuiler.
Can anyone please help here? I can't post the complete snippet due to corporate restrictions.